# How to call a ContextMenu from the menu key press?

Tags: java, android

Here's my code so far...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event ) {


    if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
    {
        // need to open the menu from here.
        //registerForContextMenu(); ???
        //openContextMenu(); ???

    }
 return super.onKeyDown(keycode,event); 
}


     @Override  
     public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
         menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");  
         menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");  
         menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");
     }

          @Override  
          public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  
              if(item.getTitle()=="Action 1"){function1(item.getItemId());}  
              else if(item.getTitle()=="Action 2"){function2(item.getItemId());}  
              else {return false;}  
          return true;  
          }  

          public void function1(int id){  
              Toast.makeText(this, "function 1 called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
          }  
          public void function2(int id){  
              Toast.makeText(this, "function 2 called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
          }
```

But I can't really figure out how to open this menu once the menu key was pressed.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

---

edit, need the menu to look like this:

[image]

Thanks, mostly works, only the menu looks like the standard Options menu, but I really need it to be like the context menu, see above. is there any way to make it look that way?

Answer (score 3):

Context menus are for long-taps on a widget. Change `onCreateContextMenu()` to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and change `onContextItemSelected()` to `onOptionsItemSelected()` (and get rid of `onKeyDown()`) to have an options menu triggered by the MENU button.

Comment: Thanks, mostly works, only the menu looks like the standard Options menu, but I really need it to be like the context menu, see above. is there any way to make it look that way?

Comment: @Roger: "I really need it to be like the context menu" -- no, you don't. Developers who break UX conventions like what you have proposed are ridiculed by users. "is there any way to make it look that way?" -- please leave the regular options menu UI alone.